# Sql query for bulk insert

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to avoid Inserting one record at a time so i need some help;

Here is an example table named `Foods`:

```
ID   UniqueID       Name        Type
1     Apple101      Apple       Fruit
2     Ban 11        Banana      Fruit
3     abc 123       Carrot      Vegetable
4     xyz123        Mango       Fruit
5     bnb123        Spinach     Vegetable
```

Now i have another Table name "`Food Data`" which has the following fields:

```
ID  UniqueID   FoodPrice    FoodExpiry
```

What i am trying to do is create the table above by recovering all the records from the table `Foods` which are `Fruits` and inserting into this table the thing is i have some external parameters (FoodPrice,FoodExpiry) . At the end i need the table `Food Data`as  below:

```
ID  UniqueID   FoodPrice    FoodExpiry
1   Apple101   100$         2 months
2   Ban 11     100$         2 months
3   xyz123     100$         2 months
```

The FoodPrice & FoodExpiry will remain the same for a given Query.

In Algorithmic terms i need an equivalent of :

```
Select UniqueID  from Foods where Type ='Fruit' and loop all the UniqueID   
and Insert into the table food Data , i want to this in one query .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that FoodData.ID is an identity column and would automatically be populated.  I also made some assumptions when declaring the types of the parameters:

```
DECLARE
  @Price decimal(19, 4)
  , @Expiry nvarchar(50)

SET @Price = 100.00
SET @Expiry = '2 months'

INSERT INTO FoodData (UniqueID, FoodPrice, FoodExpiry)
SELECT
  UniqueID
  , @Price 
  , @Expiry
FROM Food
WHERE Type = 'Fruit'
```

Comment: Hi , Just tested the query ran no error but nothing gets inserted into the table?

Comment: Couple of things - I just noticed in your description of the FoodData table, the one column is named "Food.ID" - does the column name really have a dot in it?  If so, you would need to change the insert to INSERT INTO FoodData ([Food.ID], FoodPrice, FoodExpiry) and to be real explicit, you could change the 3rd line to FoodID as [Food.ID]

Comment: Also, the question about the identity column is important.  What are the specifics of the FoodData.ID column?  Is it a plain old int or is its identity specification set to true?

Comment: Okay - same question - is FoodData.ID an identity column (meaning, that the server will automatically assign the next incremental value for you), or will you need to assign this value yourself?

Comment: FoodData.ID is an identity Column.

Comment: Thank you for your help buddy , much appretiated.